# How can I automatically record all parameters used to define a Tensorflow neural net's architecture

Tags: tensorflow

I'm experimenting with variations of a basic architecture:

```
cnn_model5 = models.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
    # Normalize.
    norm_layer,
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Dropout(0.25),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.01)),
    layers.Dropout(0.6),
    layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'),
])
```

However, `cnn5_model.summary()` only produces this output:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 normalization (Normalizati  (None, 124, 129, 1)       3         
 on)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 122, 127, 32)      320       
                                                                 
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 120, 125, 64)      18496     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPoolin  (None, 60, 62, 64)        0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 dropout_2 (Dropout)         (None, 60, 62, 64)        0         
                                                                 
 flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 238080)            0         
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 128)               30474368  
                                                                 
 dropout_3 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 258       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 30493445 (116.32 MB)
Trainable params: 30493442 (116.32 MB)
Non-trainable params: 3 (16.00 Byte)
```

It doesn't contain information about the regularizers, drop_out arguments, initializations or activation functions. So, although I can store it (along with results) to a file in an output directory, I am still not automatically recording all the relevant information needed to recreate the net.

The best approach I can think of is to create a string containing my command to create the architecture, save that string to a file in my output directory and the use Python's `exec` command to create the net.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the information in `model.get_config()['layers']`. For example:

```py
cnn_model5 = models.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Dropout(0.25),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.01)),
    layers.Dropout(0.6),
    layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'),
])
```

`cnn_model.get_config()['layers'][2]['config']` (the dropout layer):

```py
{'dtype': 'float32', 'name': 'dropout_1', 'noise_shape': None, 'rate': 0.25, 'seed': None, 'trainable': True}
```

`cnn_model.get_config()['layers'][4]['config']` (the first dense layer):

```py
{'name': 'dense_2', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'units': 128, 'activation': 'relu', 'use_bias': True, 
'kernel_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'GlorotUniform', 'config': {'seed': None}, 
'registered_name': None}, 'bias_initializer': {'module': 'keras.initializers', 'class_name': 'Zeros', 
'config': {}, 'registered_name': None}, 'kernel_regularizer': {'module': 'keras.regularizers', 'class_name': 'L2', 
'config': {'l2': 0.009999999776482582}, 'registered_name': None}, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 
'kernel_constraint': None, 'bias_constraint': None}
```

You can also get the same information in slightly different format in `cnn_model5.layers`.
If you want the information printed out, you can use:

```py
for info_ in cnn_model5.get_config()['layers']:
    print(info_['config'])
```